# list.remove(x) x not in list

Tags: python

estoy haciendo un programa que reciba números y los ordene de menor a mayor. Sin embargo me devuelve el error **list.remove(x): x not in list** y no se por qué. También he intentado cambiarlo y me daba otro error, **index out of range**. Creo que esta mal el ultimo condicional (while).

he aquí el código:

```
digito = 1
i = 1
numeros = []

# Toma de datos y calculos
while(digito != 0):
    digito = int(input(f"Digite el {i}º numero de la primitiva (0 para acabar): "))
    if(digito == 0):
        print()
    else:
        numeros.append(digito)
    i += 1

print("\n")

lista_ordenada = []
mayor = numeros[0]
long = len(numeros)
i = 0

while(numeros != []):
    for i in range(len(numeros)):
        if(mayor < numeros[i]):
            mayor = numeros[i]
        i += 1

    lista_ordenada.append(mayor)
    numeros.remove(mayor)
    i = 1
```

Comment: Buen día, si alguna respuesta te sirvió por favor acéptala, así ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a sus preguntas y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. Lectura recomendada [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No especificas nada de no usar funciones propias de python, ya validaste la opción de usar un sort para ordenar las listas y evitar el uso de ese while, sería modificar 3 líneas de código.

```
lista_ordenada = numeros
lista_ordenada.sort()
print(lista_ordenada)
```

En caso contrario y que debas realizar el ordenamiento sin funciones externas y sea netamente lógico la respuesta de @HeytalePazguato te indica como modificar la estructura del código.

Espero te sirva!

Answer (score 1):

Buen día,

Antes de pasar a la parte funcional, el código tiene algunos problemas de concepto.

Cuando tienes un ciclo `for`, por ejemplo `for i in range(len(numeros)):` el iterador `i` incrementa de forma automática, no hace falta que agregues `i += 1`.

En el caso de utilizar un rango, el rango que creas va a ir de cero a la longitud de la lista - 1, por lo que tu iterador se inicializará en cero cada vez que vaya a ejecutarse nuevamente el `for`, por lo que la línea `i = 1` está de más.

Ahora, la razón por la que no funciona es porque adentro del `while` nunca reasignas el valor de `mayor` una vez que el programa encuentra el valor mayor de una lista lo conserva por siempre y por eso en la segunda ocación que intenta eliminarlo de `numeros` ya no existe. Un ejemplo para que se entienda

Teniendo la siguiente lista `[5, 10, 1, 2]`, adentro del `while` la variable `mayor` obtendrá el valor `10` pero cuando se ha eliminado de la lista con `numeros.remove(mayor)` la variable `mayor` nunca se sobreescribe y conserva el valor de `10`, por eso en la segunda vez que se ejecuta el `while` aparece el error que mencionas

Una propuesta de solución. En lugar de asignar `mayor` al primer valor de tu lista podrías asignarlo a `None` y en el `if` que está adentro del `for` revisar si `mayor is None` o si `mayor < numeros[i]`

Ejemplo completo:

```
digito = 1
i = 1
numeros = []

# Toma de datos y calculos
while(digito != 0):
    digito = int(input(f"Digite el {i}º numero de la primitiva (0 para acabar): "))
    if(digito == 0):
        print()
    else:
        numeros.append(digito)
    i += 1

print("\n")

lista_ordenada = []
mayor = None

while(numeros != []):
    for i in range(len(numeros)):
        if (mayor is None) or (mayor < numeros[i]):
            mayor = numeros[i]
    lista_ordenada.append(mayor)
    numeros.remove(mayor)
    mayor = None
print(lista_ordenada)
```

Ejemplo de ejecución:

```
Digite el 1º numero de la primitiva (0 para acabar):  5
Digite el 2º numero de la primitiva (0 para acabar):  1
Digite el 3º numero de la primitiva (0 para acabar):  10
Digite el 4º numero de la primitiva (0 para acabar):  2
Digite el 5º numero de la primitiva (0 para acabar):  0



[10, 5, 2, 1]
```